# How to set variable JSON key

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

How do I set a value to a key in a JSON object when key is variable ?

I have a FUNCTION with this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_text_key_insert() RETURNS trigger AS  $$
...
UPDATE t_text SET all_keys->NEW.key = NEW.value
     WHERE node = NEW.node;
```

This produces the error:

```
CREATE FUNCTION
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "->"
LINE 6:  UPDATE t_text SET all_keys->NEW.key = NEW.value
```

The docs say use `->` , well I am using it! Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `NEW.value` is a string:

`SET all_keys = jsonb_set(all_keys, ARRAY[NEW.key], ('"'||NEW.value||'"')::jsonb)`